# Is it true that $c^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $ c$  be an odd natural number . We can easily show that there are infinite number of primes of the form $p \equiv 1 \pmod {4c}$ using Dirichlet theorem.

**Doubt**: Is it true that $c^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} $? If true, is it true for all such primes? or only a subset (which is still infinite)?

Euler's criterion tells us that $c^{(p-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p} $ but how do we guarantee that +1 case is true for primes of the form $1 \pmod{4c}$.

Comment: Take $c=7$ and $p=5$. Then $c^{(p-1)/2}=7^2\equiv -1\pmod{5}$

Comment: @plop But $5 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{28}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah, I didn't se the $c$ in $\pmod{4c}$

Comment: @LearningMath Then apply [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) and [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)

Comment: Assume that $q|c$ is prime. We have that $\binom{p}{q}\binom{q}{p}=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}=1$, where I am using $\binom{a}{b}$ to denote the Legendre symbol. Let's compute $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{4c+1}{q}=\binom{1}{q}=1$. Therefore $\binom{q}{p}$ is also $1$. It follows that $c$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ and by Euler's criterion you get your congruence.

Comment: @plop At this point you should probably write an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @plop Can you please explain why $$\left(\frac{4c + 1}{q}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)$$? This is the only step I don't understand.

Comment: @光復香港時代革命FreeHongKong If $a\equiv b\pmod{c}$, then $\binom{a}{c}=\binom{b}{c}$. Since $q|c$, then $4c+1\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.